# How to display character on multiplexed seven segment?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, microchip, firmware

I am designing a system which I want to display a message on a seven segment display.

I have the source code for displaying a number but how to display a character ??

```
`void UpdateDisplay(void)
{
     unsigned int SendVal;
     unsigned char Digit;
     if (flg2ms)
     {
        SEGMENT++;
        if (SEGMENT > 3) SEGMENT = 1;
        C1 = 0; C2 = 0; C3 = 0;
        switch (SEGMENT)
        {
               case 1:
                    Digit = (unsigned char) (Voltage_INT / 100);
                    break;
               case 2:
                    Digit = (unsigned char) ((Voltage_INT / 10) % 10);
                    break;
               case 3:
                    Digit = (unsigned char) (Voltage_INT % 10);
                    break;
        }
        SendVal = DriveSegment[Digit] & 0x7F; // Make bit 7 zero
        PORTB = SendVal;
        switch (SEGMENT)
        {
               case 1:
                    C1 = 1;
                    break;
               case 2:
                    C2 = 1;
                    break;
               case 3:
                    C3 = 1;
                    break;
        }
        flg2ms = 0;              // Clear flag
     }
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Expand `DriveSegment` to include the additional glyphs you want to display.

Comment: How will i separate strings ?? any pseudo code ??

Comment: We usually use spaces for that. Just use the appropriate element in the array.